# How to create a read only user for rsync?

Tags: ssh, rsync

I have A and B linux servers. I have many users with their home directories in `/home`.

I want to run rsync in B to sync `/home` from A. I want to consider the following:

- I want to use SSH key auth for rsync.
- I want to use non-sudo user for rsync.
- Some files in users' home dirs have 400 permission. So normal user can't access it.
- I don't want B to be able to has write permission in A.

What is the best approach to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky, and there is likely no simple way to do this while retaining the 400 permission in the Linux file structure that I am aware of.

I might try using some kind of overlay/[UnionFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS), create a backup user and give that user full access to the UnionFS version of the file system but mount the UnionFS as readonly for that user - or failing that, mount the underlying file system as read-only and then discard any writes made on the file system, allowing the user to use the overlayed one.

I prototyped this in Ubuntu as follows (only very lightly tested - probably needs tweeking) -

As root:

```
apt install unionfs-fuse
mkdir /path/to/overlayfs
unionfs -o allow_other,ro,uid=1001 /path/to/mount /path/to/overlayfs
```

Where `1001` is the userid associated with the backup account.    `ro` of-course says to mount filesystem as read only and `allow_other` allows us to override the default permissions.

To mount this with fstab, the syntax is weird and the line will look like

```
unionfs#/path/to/mount=ro      /path/to/overlayfs  fuse    allow_other,ro,uid=1001        0       0
```

(Ref: https://grangerx.wordpress.com/2010/12/31/using-fuse-unionfs-with-centos-5-5-i686/ )

Comment: An alternative solution to the problem (but not the question you asked) might be to use an LVM system, create a snapshot, mount the snapshot giving backup user full perms and then back up the snapshot.   You could do something similar with ZFS to I expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well. How can I make it automount after reboot? i.e., in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: See updated post

Comment: Wouldn’t this mess up all the file owner UIDs?

Comment: @danielb Good point - it would change the ownership on tje backup - but it should be fairly trivial to write a script or 1 liner to restore ownership assuming the standard user own /home/user format

Answer (score 0):

You can use a “forced command” to restrict what users connecting over SSH can do. This way, you can safely give super user access over SSH. You can either set this up in `sshd_config` using the [`ForceCommand`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5#ForceCommand) option, possibly in a `Match` block. Or you can put this directly in `authorized_keys`, allowing you to create special-purpose SSH keys. It could look like this:

```
command="/var/lib/backup-operator/.ssh/allowed-commands.sh",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIDcnXDtzZygrdwpxwsTe+nr7hwF6quQNkwhoROBKPagv user@client
```

The script I have is this:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
    "rsync --server --sender -vlogDtpre.iLsfxCIvu . /tank/backup/mysql/")
        exec rsync --server --sender -vlogDtpre.iLsfxCIvu . /tank/backup/mysql/
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Access denied."
        echo "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" > /var/lib/backup-operator/last-failed-command
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

It’s brittle: New `rsync` versions sometime require changing the allowed command with different switches.

I could easily add another block for a different directory to back up. I could also smuggle in `sudo` (which must be appropriately set up) to elevate the `rsync` process.

---

If you want to properly sync or backup home folders, you must not change their UID, GID or permissions. The only way to get all files anyway is to be *root* (or to have the corresponding *capability*, but I never used those).

Answer (score 0):

Mount your filesystems read-only for rsync with [systemd-run](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-run.html). See [systemd.exec(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.exec.html) for details. This solution requires a privileged user that is able to bind mount filesystems, though.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Run rsync from SSH with read-only filesystems

# Execute this script from your authorized_keys file:
# command="/usr/local/sbin/rsnapshot-rsync",no-pty,no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding...

case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
rsync\ *)
 systemd-run -qGP -p PrivateDevices=true -p ProtectSystem=strict $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
 ;;
*)
 echo "Access denied" 1>&2
 exit 1
 ;;
esac
```

Optionally, drop the privileges by running rsync with `--uid <USER> $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`.

I've shortened the above example. I'd create a dedicated user such as "rsnapshot" and either execute systemd-run with sudo or create the file */etc/polkit-1/rules.d/50-rsnapshot.rules* if polkit is available.

```javascript
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
        subject.user == "rsnapshot") {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```